No allure-results after running ReqnRoll test
I have an MS Test running NUnit with RoqnRoll. After dotnet test, as per Allure instructions, the tests pass but I don't seem to have any allure-results. The allure config says "directory":"allure-results" but I do not have any other config anywhere. Is there a new logger or something that I should add?

you can find the allure-results  in bin folder
